# How to deploy monorepo with using library on Heroku

Tags: javascript, typescript, heroku, deployment, nestjs

I have a repository on Github with monorepo project which includes library written with using `NestJS` framework. Structure like below:

```
MAIN FOLDER:
- apps:
-- projectA
-- projectB
- libs:
-- libraryA
-- libraryB
```

`ProjectA` and `ProjectB` using both of the libraries from `libs` folder,

How to deploy on heroku `projectA` and `projectB` so that they use resources from my libraries?

And another question,in package.json I ahve this command to build `projectA` after deployment on heroku:

```
"start": "node dist/apps/projectA/main.js",
```

how to deploy `projectB` when in this package.json path to the `main.js` must be different?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `projectA` and `projectB` is other nestjs project?

Comment: @WangLiang, hmmm yes, I'm using this pattern: https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo

Comment: I added new question but in this same topic

Answer (score 0):

I was looking online for the solution, but did not find one. So I created a new Heroku Buildpack.

So basically what I do is update the package.json scripts with additional app being set as `NEST_APP` from Heroku config variables. This is done before `nodejs` buildpack is run, which then executes the scripts as usual, defined in `Procfile`.

Most of the time `start:prod` is executed on Heroku, which has a specific distribution folder, so I also change the folder location for the script.

Buildpack available on GitHub: https://github.com/blubblub/heroku-buildpack-nest-monorepo